# A problem that isn't really a problem

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or, more likely, a phrase--along the lines of "Hobson's choice," "busman's holiday," or "Pyrrhic victory"--to describe a problem that isn't really a problem. An example might be the "problem" of having too much evidence for something you are trying to prove.

"First-world problem" comes pretty close to what I'm looking for, but I'd appreciate a phrase that telegraphs a more focused irony and is perhaps a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: *I should have such problems!*

Comment: If you're talking about "a problem that isn't really a problem" you might say it's a ***non-problem*** (or more likely, a ***non-issue***).

Comment: A problem which is not (one) or a false problem....

Comment: Similar: [Generic form of “first world problems”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244246), [An expression that is the opposite of Mortons's fork](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently heard this described as a *champagne problem*.

from the [Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/champagne-problem):

> *champagne problem* noun
>
> a problem that, in reality, demonstrates one's good fortune.

Answer (score 2):

For the 'too much [evidence] ...' example, a fitting expression is

**an embarrassment of riches**.

From [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/an-embarrassment-of-riches):

> *an embarrassment of riches*  [formal]:
>
> so many good things or ​people that it is ​impossible to ​decide which
>   of them you ​want

More generally,

'**I wish I had *your* problems**' (as bib suggests)

(meaning 'I wish I [merely] had [what you consider to be] {your} problems')

is used. A clear example is [this from metrolyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/everyday-another-conflict-lyrics-naked-aggression.html):

> He said I wish I had your problems cause they're
>
> Nothing compared to mine.

(though I wouldn't use this source very often).

Comment: Good answer; thanks. However I think "embarrassment" used to be not so negative (as perhaps it wasn't when this expression was coined)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a term for the result rather than the cause is of interest  ...

If you are working on *a problem that isn't really a problem* you could end up doing **busy work**.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_work):

> **Busy work** (also referred to as **make-work** and **busywork**) can refer to activity that is undertaken to pass time and stay busy but in and of itself has no actual value. [...]
>
> Busy work also occurs in business, military and other settings, in situations where people may be required to be present but may lack the opportunities, skills or need to do something more productive.
>
> People may engage in busy work to maintain an appearance of activity, in order to avoid criticism of being inactive or idle.